# Why each place in a number is ten times greater than place to its immediate right number ?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

am beginner to math and i have an question : I know that each place in a
whole number is ten times greater than the place to its immediate right , but why ?

Comment: Are you claiming that, for instance in $123$, the number $1$ is ten times greater than $2$?

Comment: @GitGud No. I think he is talking about order of magnitude.

Comment: your statement only applies to decimal number representation. In hexadecimal, each place has an order of magnitude of 16 times that to its immediate right.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of orders of answers to this.

$10$ because we have $10$ fingers (incl thumbs) is one.

A consistent base (whether $10$ or $60$ or something else) because that means we can more easily learn the basic facts for addition and multiplication. [The distributive law makes it possible to multiply any pair of numbers knowing only a few basic facts for addition and multiplication].

Number systems with non-constant bases are known, but you wouldn't make them the first thing to teach to children - except when telling the time.

The decimal system works.

What sort of answer are you hoping for?